# Tumblr theme limitation

Tags: html, css, tumblr

In [my Tumblr](http://blog.omarayoub.com), there is a "Likes" column on the right. I changed the number of displayed "liked" posts to 15 here:

```
<h3 class="section-title"><a href="http://www.tumblr.com/liked/by/{Name}">{lang:Likes}</a></h3>
{Likes limit="15" width="200" summarize="200"}
```

but it doesn't display more than 5. The highest number it does display is 10. I want it to go all the way to the bottom, or as closest to that point as possible. Any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the API, I believe you can get 20 likes: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-likes

If you want to get more, you will need to grab the first 20, then use `offset` to get 20 onwards.